# Self Hosted Agent on macOS not working with Azure Pipeline

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, pipeline

This is an issue I've been facing for the past week.

I have an M1 Mac Mini setup as a self-hosted agent to run iOS related builds/archives through Azure Pipelines.

I'm able to build/archive locally on the machine itself using terminal. Mobile provisioning and code signing are setup and working fine.

When I run the agent interactively using `run.sh`, I am able to run the pipeline successfully. When I try running the agent as a launchd service using `./svc.sh install` -> `./svc.sh start`, it always fails with the same error:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ValidateEmbeddedBinary /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<app-name>/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/<app-name>.app (in target '<app-name>' from project '<project>')
(1 failure)
##[error]Bash exited with code '65'.
```

The command I'm using to archive is

`xcodebuild -workspace ~/repos/<project>/<project>.xcworkspace -scheme <app-name> -allowProvisioningUpdates clean archive -archivePath build/<app-name> -destination generic/platform=iOS`

Again, this command works when I run it locally and when I run the agent interactively.

I removed app/project names for privacy reasons.

I've searched high and low as to why this error is occurring and I've tried virtually all suggestions to fix it. For the life of me I don't know why the command would work locally and when the agent is run interactively, but does not work when the agent is run as a launchd service.

Edit: I’ve noticed a pattern: the archive fails with that error after every successful run. In other words the command successfully archives but when I run it again, it fails. If I run it once more, it’s successful. This occurs when running it through Azure Pipelines and locally via terminal. I have no words!

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this having the same issue: I "solved" it by having a retry in the pipeline. If it doesn't work the first time it'll work the second time. I can't explain why.